# Something wrong happening with split()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file "luawrite", in which i am splitting each line into 4 columns and i am dividing (3rd column value multiplied by 8) with the 4th column value. The file luawrite looks like this:

```
0.012281001     00:1c:c4:c2:1f:fe       1441    44000000
0.012285001     00:1c:c4:c2:1f:fe       1441    44000000
0.012288001     00:1c:c4:c2:1f:fe       1441    44000000
0.012292001     00:1c:c4:c2:1f:fe       1441    44000000
0.012295001     00:1c:c4:c2:1f:fe       1441    44000000
0.012299001     00:1c:c4:c2:1f:fe       1441    44000000
0.012302001     00:1c:c4:c2:1f:fe       1441    44000000
```

The code i have written for this is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import collections
result = collections.defaultdict(int)

with open("luawrite", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
            hashes = line.split()
            val1 = int(hashes[2])
            val2 = int(hashes[3])
            k = (val1*8)/val2
            print k
```

I am using python 2.6. But the solution i get are all zeros.  Where is the problem in this code, please tell me. It might be a small mistake but i am not able to find it. Thanks!

Comment: @freakish i edited the post. The output i am getting are all zeros.

Comment: `for line in f.readlines():`?

Comment: @GerardYin: No, there is no reason to ever do `for line in f.readlines():` instead of `for line in f:` (except for backward compat for very old versions of Python).

Comment: For future reference, try printing out `val1` and `val2` to see if they're different from what you expect. If you found out that one of them was 0, you'd know where the problem was. On the other hand, if you found out that they were `'1441'` and `'44000000'`, you'd know the problem wasn't "something wrong happening with split()", but something with `int` or the division. Even if that didn't solve the problem for you, it would help others answer it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In py2.x integer division truncates the output, so you'll get `0` as output here.:

use `float`:

```
k = (val1*8)/float(val2) #or just do: (val1*8.0)/val2   #numerator is now a float
```

Demo:

```
>>> 2/3
0
>>> 2/3.0
0.6666666666666666

>>> 2/float(3)
0.6666666666666666
```

So **at least** one operand must be float to get the correct output.

You can also import py3.x division operator's functionality in py2.x:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 2/3
0.6666666666666666
```

Another alternative is `operator.truediv`:

```
>>> import operator
>>> operator.truediv(2,3)
0.6666666666666666
```

Comment: Alternatively, multiply `val1` by `8.0` instead of just `8`

Comment: or `from __future__ import division`